# Magento 2. How can I properly extend vendor/composer/installed.json?

Tags: magento2, composer, third-party-module, version

- I assume that **installed.json** contains all the dependencies needed for **Magento**.
- How can I properly extend **vendor/composer/installed.json?**

Context:

- Magento has a **hard** dependency on one of the libraries, more specifically a specific version of a third party **module msp/recaptcha:2.0.2**. I want to update it to 2.1.2.
- Now if it were a softer dependency (~2.0.2) I could have done so from composer.json as described in the answer of this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276474/upgrade-magento-vendor-moduledependencylibrary-to-a-newer-version?noredirect=1#comment394853_276474)

By this point it should be clear what I need to achieve and why. Please ask for any more details if needed. Thanks.

Comment: In your opinion do you think it should be a soft dependency?

Comment: Not necessarily. I suspect they their reasons to make it a hard dependency, but still I should have a way to extend|change this (for this library or any other), at my own responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by extend.

Certainly this route works.

So remove original via composer

```
    "replace": {
        "msp/recaptcha": "*"
    },
```

`composer install`

```
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing msp/recaptcha (2.0.2)
Removing Msp/Recaptcha
```

https://github.com/magento/magespecialist_ReCaptcha/tree/v2.1.2

Extract 2.1.2 to app/code/MSP/ReCaptcha

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Check `setup_module` table and MSP_ReCaptcha entry says 1.5.0.

Matches what's in code

https://github.com/magento/magespecialist_ReCaptcha/blob/v2.1.2/etc/module.xml#L24

Site seems functional.  That's good enough for me.  I'm now in control of this extension.

Comment: :) Thanks for the answer, this is what I ended up doing as well. I'm wondering if there is another way. A "Magento" way. I'll keep the question open if you don't mind.

Comment: ha! yes the "Magento" way isn't always the way everyone else does it